# ECDsa signed PDF showing "Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed" error in Adobe Reader

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext7, ecdsa

I've signed a PDF document with iText 8.0.2 using an ECDSA (SHA-256) certificate. Unfortunately the Adobe Reader says the signature is invalid, with the reason *"Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed"*. Since the digital signing topic is not my specialty, I cannot figure out how and where to look for the error. Can someone guide me?

```
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Signatures;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace PdfSignTest
{   
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: PdfSignTest.exe pdfFilePath pfxFilePath");
                Console.WriteLine(" - pdfFilePath: path of an unsigned pdf file which will be signed");
                Console.WriteLine(" - pfxFilePath: path of a pfx file containing the full certificate chain");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            string srcPath = args[0];
            string cerPath = args[1];
            string dstPath = srcPath.Replace(".pdf", ".signed.at." + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss") + ".pdf");

            var signed = SignPdfECC(srcPath, cerPath);
            File.WriteAllBytes(dstPath, signed);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File {0} successfully signed and saved as {1}.", srcPath, dstPath));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static byte[] SignPdfECC(string unsignedPdfPath, string certificatePfxPath)
        {
            byte[] certificatePfx = File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePfxPath);

            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(unsignedPdfPath))
            using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, mem, new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());
                X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate(certificatePfx, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                X509Certificate2 signatureCert = new X509Certificate2(cert);
                ECDsa pk = signatureCert.GetECDsaPrivateKey();
                IExternalSignature signature = new EcdsaSignature(pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
                iText.Bouncycastle.X509.X509CertificateBC[] chain = new iText.Bouncycastle.X509.X509CertificateBC[] { new iText.Bouncycastle.X509.X509CertificateBC(new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate(signatureCert.GetRawCertData())) };
                signer.SignDetached(signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
                return mem.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    public class EcdsaSignature : IExternalSignature
    {
        private readonly string _encryptionAlgorithm;
        private readonly string _hashAlgorithm;
        private readonly ECDsa _pk;

        public EcdsaSignature(ECDsa pk, string hashAlgorithm)
        {
            _pk = pk;
            _hashAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.GetDigest(DigestAlgorithms.GetAllowedDigest(hashAlgorithm));
            _encryptionAlgorithm = "ECDSA";
        }

        public string GetDigestAlgorithmName()
        {
            return "SHA-256";
        }

        public virtual string GetEncryptionAlgorithm()
        {
            return _encryptionAlgorithm;
        }

        public virtual string GetHashAlgorithm()
        {
            return _hashAlgorithm;
        }

        public string GetSignatureAlgorithmName()
        {
            return "ECDSA";
        }

        public ISignatureMechanismParams GetSignatureMechanismParameters()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public virtual byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
        {
            return _pk.SignData(message, new HashAlgorithmName(_hashAlgorithm));
        }
    }
}
```

I removed all the additional features, like TSA and LTV, expecting that maybe one of these steps caused the error. I also tried with a test certificate taken from the OpenSSL test certificates collection, and a test PDF downloaded from w3.org. All of these are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NucHLeYBjZ4NP3ijrAXtk8ZqAwdW5ipY?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `ECDsa.SignData` returns the signature value in PLAIN format while iText uses the OID for ECDSA signatures in DER format. Thus, before returning the signature value from `EcdsaSignature.Sign` you have to transform it from PLAIN to DER format, e.g. like this:

```csharp
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math;

[...]

public virtual byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
{
    return PlainToDer(_pk.SignData(message, new HashAlgorithmName(_hashAlgorithm)));
}

byte[] PlainToDer(byte[] plain)
{
    int valueLength = plain.Length / 2;
    BigInteger r = new BigInteger(1, plain, 0, valueLength);
    BigInteger s = new BigInteger(1, plain, valueLength, valueLength);
    return new DerSequence(new DerInteger(r), new DerInteger(s)).GetEncoded(Asn1Encodable.Der);
}
```

*([SignWithEcdsaCert](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext8/blob/master/src/test/csharp/signature/SignWithEcdsaCert.cs) class `EcdsaSignature` methods)*

The `PlainToDer` helper method has been borrowed from the [`X509Certificate2Signature`](https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/blob/develop/itext/itext.publications/itext.publications.signing-examples.simple/iText/SigningExamples/Simple/X509Certificate2Signature.cs) implementation of `IExternalSignature` from the iText Knowledge Base article [Digital Signing with iText](https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/digital-signing-with-itext) / [Part I - Overview and Simple Cases](https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/part-i-overview-and-simple-cases) / [Signing with .NET CryptoAPI/CNG Keys](https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/part-i-overview-and-simple-cases#PartI-OverviewandSimpleCases-Signingwith.NETCryptoAPI/CNGKeys).

Comment: Thank you @mkl, it worked. I also put back the TSA and LTV features, those are working fine also. Inspired from the [X509Certificate2Signature](https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/blob/develop/itext/itext.publications/itext.publications.signing-examples.simple/iText/SigningExamples/Simple/X509Certificate2Signature.cs) class you mentioned, I made a universal signer method for both RSA and ECDSA signatures.